# Suppose that A and B are both nxn matrices, and that λ is an eigenvalue for both A and B. Prove that λ is an eigenvalue for the matrix product AB.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

From the information I'm given, I can see that since matrix A and B have the same eigenvalue, then these matrices are similar then.  I'm not sure if that is correct but if it is, how would I use this to prove that matrix product AB will have the same eigenvalue as A and B.

edit:
Instead of proving λ is a eigenvalue for the matrix product AB, what about is λ an eigenvector for the matrix product AB? or would this also not be true?

Comment: Thats not true. If you let 2 by 2 matrices A=B=diag(2,2). Then AB=diag(4,4). diag here means diagonal matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true. If $A$ and $B$ both also have the same eigenvector, say $v$, then $ABv = A \lambda v = \lambda Av = \lambda^2 v,$ so $\lambda^2$ (not $\lambda$) is an eigenvalue of $AB.$ But if the eigenvector is not the same, the eigenvalues of $AB$ could have no relationship to $\lambda.$

Comment: Instead of proving λ is eigenvalue of AB,  how would I prove λ is an eigenvector for AB?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ had the same eigenvector $v$ (even with different eigenvalues), then you can show, using basically the same argument I gave above, that $v$ is also an eigenvector of $AB.$

Answer (score 4):

Your claim is not true. For example consider the matrix $-I_n$. The only eigenvalue is $-1$. However,$-I_n^2 = I_n$ has eigenvalue $1$.